# (iOS lldb) Unable to debug past a splash/loading screen

Tags: debugging, debuggers, ios, lldb

I'm trying to lldb debug this certain iOS application.

Its behavior is that when I click the application, the splash/loading screen comes up, then the main activity.

However, whenever I try to debug the app via lldb, it gets stuck in the splash/loading screen. Even when I set breakpoints, it doesn't stop, but dwell in the screen.

For example, when I process connect via lldb, this shows up:

```
Process 2517 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x000000010496d444 dyld` dyld::findMappedRange(unsigned long)  + 32
dyld`dyld::findMappedRange:
->  0x10496d444 <+32>: cbz    x8, 0x10496d460           ; <+60>
    0x10496d448 <+36>: ldur   x13, [x12, #-0x8]
    0x10496d44c <+40>: cmp    x13, x0
    0x10496d450 <+44>: b.hi   0x10496d460               ; <+60>
    0x10496d454 <+48>: ldr    x13, [x12]
    0x10496d458 <+52>: cmp    x13, x0
    0x10496d45c <+56>: b.hi   0x10496d47c               ; <+88>
    0x10496d460 <+60>: add    x11, x11, #0x1            ; =0x1 
Target 0: () stopped.

thread #1: tid = 0x1e2a0, 0x000000010496d444 'dyld`dyld::findMappedRange(unsigned long) + 32, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
```

Then, I `continue`, but the splash/loading screen doesn't process to the next activity.

```
Process 2517 resuming
```

So I `process interrupt` to stop, and lldb shows the following:

```
Process 2517 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x000000018348816c libsystem_kernel.dylib` mach_msg_trap  + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
->  0x18348816c <+8>: ret    
libsystem_kernel.dylib'mach_msg_overwrite_trap:    0x183488170 <+0>: mov    x16, #-0x20
    0x183488174 <+4>: svc    #0x80
    0x183488178 <+8>: ret    
libsystem_kernel.dylib'semaphore_signal_trap:    0x18348817c <+0>: mov    x16, #-0x21
    0x183488180 <+4>: svc    #0x80
    0x183488184 <+8>: ret    
libsystem_kernel.dylib'semaphore_signal_all_trap:    0x183488188 <+0>: mov    x16, #-0x22
Target 0: () stopped.

* thread #1: tid = 0x1e2a0, 0x000000018348816c 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  thread #7: tid = 0x1e646, 0x00000001834a6314 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`__semwait_signal + 8, name = 'DeadLockMonitorThread'
  thread #8: tid = 0x1e647, 0x000000018348816c 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread'
  thread #11: tid = 0x1e667, 0x000000018348816c 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'APFileLog'
  thread #17: tid = 0x1e66d, 0x000000018348816c 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader'
  thread #18: tid = 0x1e67b, 0x000000018348816c 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'AVAudioSession Notify Thread'
  thread #19: tid = 0x1e68b, 0x00000001834a5e1c 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 8
  thread #20: tid = 0x1e6ea, 0x000000018348816c 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8, name = 'com.alipay.antlog'
  thread #21: tid = 0x1e70c, 0x00000001834a6a88 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
  thread #22: tid = 0x1e719, 0x00000001834a6a88 'libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is not going past the splash/loading screen?

Thanks